# Launching Processing tool User Interface using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, gui

I am trying to launch the UI of a processing algorithm using Python script but I cannot find a simple way for it (aside double clicking on it in the process toolbox of course). The plugin is a water network simulator and I just want to launch its pre-processing UI without using `process.runalg()` because this needs to enter arguments and I don't need it.

Some ways would be to trigger processes available in process toolbox or sending command to commander from python console. but I have no clue how and I am searching for 2 hours now, no results.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for the answer.. Although I was doing PyQGIS exclusively for my thesis so I passed this stage and didn't have it anymore until now I tested it in some other PCs. but thanks any ways :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do that from the QGIS Python console in this way:

```
# Import both Processing and CommanderWindow 
#   classes from the Processing framework. 
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
from processing.gui.CommanderWindow import CommanderWindow

# Then get the algorithm you're interested in (for instance, Join Attributes):
alg = Processing.getAlgorithm("qgis:joinattributestable")

# Instantiate the commander window and open the algorithm's interface 
cw = CommanderWindow(iface.mainWindow(), iface.mapCanvas())
if alg is not None:
    cw.runAlgorithm(alg)
```

That's it! You get the algorithm's UI open.

[image]

Note: *You can get the names of the available algorithms by entering these lines in the QGIS Python console:*

```
import processing
processing.alglist()
```

*Tested in QGIS 2.10.1, Processing framework v.2.9.1 and v.2.10.1*

---

EDIT:

If you find errors when running the code snippet above, chances are you're using QGIS v2.16.0, v2.16.1, or v2.16.2. To solve the [issue](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/15562), install QGIS v2.16.3.

Comment: tested also for the upcoming QGIS3, thanks!

Comment: Hmm, in QGIS 3.4.1 I can't import `CommanderWindow`.. Any idea how to fire up a Processing GUI in the current API?

Answer (score 3):

To open a processing algorithm GUI on QGIS 3.x series, you need to do the following:

```py
import processing
processing.execAlgorithmDialog('native:buffer')
# Can take parameters to prefill the GUI fields
processing.execAlgorithmDialog('native:buffer', parameters= {'INPUT':iface.activeLayer(),'DISTANCE':10,'SEGMENTS':5,'END_CAP_STYLE':0,'JOIN_STYLE':0,'MITER_LIMIT':2,'DISSOLVE':False,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```

You can get list of algorithms identifier and associated name with

```py
for alg in QgsApplication.processingRegistry().algorithms():
        print(alg.id(), "->", alg.displayName())
```

Code above is an excerpt from official doc ["Using processing algorithms from the console"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html)