# Launch Processing tool UI in pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3

This is a duplicate of [Launching Processing tool User Interface using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156633/launching-processing-tool-user-interface-using-pyqgis). However, the answer provided is not correct for QGIS 3.4.1.

`from processing.gui.CommanderWindow import CommanderWindow`

results in a

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'processing.gui.CommanderWindow'`

Anyone know the current syntax to launch a processing tool from pyqgis, so that I can call one from e.g. a plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In qgis 3 this is:

```
 initial_params={}
 results = processing.execAlgorithmDialog('algorithm_id', initial_params)
```

The initial parameters argument can be used to specify the initial values to populate the dialog with.